# Erro ao enviar dados para o php com ajax no wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, wordpress

Tenho este formulário:

```
<select id="mudar_produto">
    <option></option> 
    <option value="#produto_1">Novo Produto Higiene</option> 
</select>
<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1"> 
<form class="form-validate" id="feedback_form">
    <div class="campo">
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        </div>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" type="button">Registo</button>
</form>
</section>
```

Tenho este ajax para enviar os dados sem fazer refresh à página e limpar os inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "inserir",
                    data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
                            $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                        } else {
                            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
</script>
```

Na página inserir tenho o código php:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx"; 
$username = "xxxxxx"; 
$password = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbname = "xxxxxxxx"; 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
$name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
$unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';
if (!empty($name)) && (!empty($unid)) { 

    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}    

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

Mas quando clico no botão para registar recebo o seguinte erro na consola:

> POST http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/index.php/inserir 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

e não insere na tabela da base de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebi, você tem um erro em um `if` no seu código `PHP`, conforme abaixo:

***Código com erro***

```
if (!empty($name)) && (!empty($unid)) { 

    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

**Código correto:**

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($unid)){
        echo 'true';
} else {
        echo 'false';
}
```

Uma dica, sempre que você ver esse erro 500, procure abrir o arquivo de log de erro do seu PHP, ali vai estar descrito o motivo do erro estar ocorrendo e você resolverá o problema mais facilmente, ou então habilite os logs de erros na própria tela do navegador enquanto está desenvolvendo:

Informe os seguintes parâmetros direto no arquivo php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```